# View data by id in laravel with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I was make create update and delete, but i get error to view data by ID. please help me :
this is my `script.js`

```
function dataModal(){
    var tableDatas = $("#datas");
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/dataLowongan";

    $("#datas").empty();
    $.get(route, function(res){
        $(res).each(function(key,value){
            tableDatas.append("<tr><td>"+value.id+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+value.judul+"</td>" +
                "<td><button value="+value.id+" onClick='EditModal(this);' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Edit</button>"+
                " <button value="+value.id+" onClick='HapusModal(this);' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#dellModal'>Hapus</button>"+
                " <button value="+value.id+" onClick='ViewModal(this);' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#viewModalBlade'>View</button></td></tr>"
            );
        });
    });
}
```

this is function for View

```
function ViewModal(btn){
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/lowongan/"+btn.value+"/edit";

    $.get(route, function(res){
        $("#id").val(res.id);
        $("#judul").val(res.judul);
    });
}
```

i getting error on this, my modal.blade to view the view datas.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="viewModalBlade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ $datas->judul}}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Undefined variable: datas @Tim

Comment: It seems like you are not assigning a `$datas` variable when rendering the html. Could you please edit your question and show us the code of your controller?